# Is this the correct pronunciation of "heinous" in any English-speaking country?

Tags: pronunciation, canadian-english

I've never heard "heinous" pronounced "HI-ness" before; I always thought the only valid pronunciation was "HAY-ness."

Is "HI-ness" a valid pronunciation of "heinous" in any English-speaking country? The speaker in this case is a Canadian: [Professor Jordan Peterson](https://youtu.be/bBu74aRI3g8?t=358).

[image]

I'm British and, at least in the UK, I only recall ever hearing "[HAY-ness,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1fApqoDOXE)" although that video says an alternative British pronunciation is "HE-nus." Either way, it's still not "HI-ness"!

Cambridge Dictionary also indicates the same pronunciation for both [British and American English](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/heinous).

I even found an interview with the lead singer of an American blues band called the "Heinous Hounds." Both the band member and the interviewer (both American) also pronounce it the [same way](https://youtu.be/_tXteX_Cc6s?t=927).

[image]

This question was not intended to be a peeve or a *criticism* of Professor Peterson in any way; I have the utmost respect for the man! It's actually precisely *because* I know Peterson to be an intelligent and articulate speaker that I was intrigued to hear him make what sounded like a possible pronunciation error.

Comment: This is how the guttersnipes in my fair lady would say it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a peeve

Comment: Not at all. I wasn't sure if he was simply mispronouncing it or if there was some other possible explanation. It turns out it could have something to do with the fact that he speaks French and that may have influenced him.

Comment: Besides, even if this *was* a peeve, and it's not, that wouldn't automatically make the question off topic regardless of whether or not it was *actually* off topic. The two things aren't mutually exclusive. Please don't presume to know *why* someone is asking a question.

Comment: Honestly, I always thought that it was either hay-eh-ness or hi-eh-ness, with the "-eh-" being very light in either case. (US english)

Comment: Actually, *both* of these recordings are pronouncing as I indicated above.  There is a *very slight* "-eh-" after the first syllable in either case.  That's always how I've heard it pronounced (though it is not a commonly spoken word).

Comment: Heinous is such a good example of "booklish" or "onlyreaditism"... https://ask.metafilter.com/266681/Looking-for-a-term-mispronouncing-a-word-youve-only-ever-read

Comment: @RBarryYoung There are only two syllables, not three.

Comment: @tchrist I do not know how you count the syllables for concatenated slight vowel sounds like this.  However, to be clear, I have always pronounced and have always heard it pronounced in the US as either *hay(ə),ness* or *hi(ə),ness*, as it is in the two clips in the question. I have never heard it without that very slight (ə), hitch at the end of the first syllable.  I am not contending that that is another syllable.  I am contending that that is an additional phoneme that is *very* common in the US.

Comment: Professor Jordan Peterson should take a lesson from Bill and Ted. Despite lacking intellectual prowess, they could at least pronounce "heinous" correctly. 

Comment: @RBarryYoung The Canadian speaker in the first clip is using the phoneme we refer to as the PRICE vowel, which is nonstandard. In contrast, both the American and the Australian in the second clip are each using what we call the FACE vowel, which is standard. There is a phonetic offglide in that diphthong as realized by all three speakers, but this is perfectly expected; it does not change the phoneme from PRICE to FACE, which is something else and is precisely why it is perceived as a different and indeed nonstandard pronunciation. See my updated answer for links to all this.

Comment: @Mentalist check this out! https://youtu.be/Pm1rif1fASk?t=369

Comment: @MrEthernet "Hyenas!" ...brilliant! :-)

Comment: When I was in the Navy I served with a guy who was taking a course on How To Sound Smarter. He got a list of words every other week or so, with definitions but no pronunciation guidance, which he was supposed to memorize and use. It was *interesting* when he used his new words - but I'm afraid the course failed in its primary objective. :-}

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica that's the problem with learning a new word from what you read and not hearing it spoken. I tried to sound intelligent in a job interview once by using the word "mnemonic." I used it in the right context but I pronounced it all wrong and with an extra syllable: "muh-NE-monic." 

Comment: error according to who? it is a different pronunciation

Comment: @green_ideas perhaps the broader question here is whether the pronunciations outlined in the dictionary can be considered to be an exhaustive list.

Comment: you need to use a Pronunciation Dictionary that shows regional and dialectal differences, and even those are not exhaustive

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## For *heinous* say: /ˈheɪ.nəs/ like *greyness*
               — ɴᴏᴛ /ˈhaɪ.nəs/ like *dryness*
               — ɴᴏʀ /ˈhiː.ni.əs/ like *Phineas*

The Canadian speaker in the first clip is using the phoneme we refer to as [the **PRICE** vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set#Wells_Standard_Lexical_Sets_for_English). This phoneme is by convention normatively written as the diphthong /aɪ/ in both Received Pronunciation and General American, but the exact phonetics for that phoneme [vary by dialect and speaker](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/right). He appears to saying [ɐi] there. This is a ***non-standard*** pronunciation of *heinous* according to the OED. He should not be using the PRICE vowel there.

In contrast, both the American and the Australian in the second clip are each using the phoneme which we call [the **FACE** vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set#Wells_Standard_Lexical_Sets_for_English). This phoneme is by convention normatively written as the diphthong /eɪ/ in both Received Pronunciation and General American, but as with all phonemes, the exact phonetics for that phoneme [vary by dialect and speaker](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/naked). The American appears to saying [eɪ] there, and the Australian perhaps [ɛɪ]. Those are two allophones of the same phoneme, so exactly which gets used phonetically will not change which word one hears said. This is a perfectly ***standard*** pronunciation of *heinous* according to the OED because it uses the FACE vowel.

In other words, *heinous* **should** rhyme with *greyness* and *anus*, **ɴᴏᴛ** with *dryness* and *sinus*.

## Quoth the OED

The [OED gives a primary pronunciation for *heinous*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/85504) in both the UK and the US alike with the first syllable pronounced like  *hay* as in *hayfields*, the so-called FACE vowel.  However, it also gives an alternate, secondary UK pronunciation whose first syllable is like *hee* as in *tee hee*, which is the FLEECE vowel.  The OED presents no evidence that *heinous* is ever pronounced with a first syllable like *high* as in *high school*, which is the PRICE vowel.

Historical spellings dating from Middle English include both *heynous* and *hainous*. Its etymon, however, is French *haineux*, in Old French *haïnos, haïneus*, from *haine* hatred, from *ha-ïr* meaning to hate. So the “high” pronunciation was historically there in Old French and perhaps in Middle English, but never that I can see in modern versions of either language.

## Other References

I ***have*** heard native speakers of English from [the Appalachia region of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachian_English) use the "highness" pronunciation, and like the OP found this peculiar. I have yet to uncover any documentation in support of this variation.

However, others have noticed this and called it wrong. For example, there’s a blog post by V. J. Singal from 2011 that calls this [the mispronounced word of the week](http://thearticulateprofessional.blogspot.com/2011/01/heinous-mispronounced-word-of-week.html):

> This past week, while speaking about the tragedy in Tucson, numerous Americans have used the word “heinous” [pronounced HAY-nus] to describe Jared Loughner’s crime. No surprise there. What has amazed me is the number of prominent and well-educated people who have mispronounced that word, including University of Arizona President Robert Shelton. In his opening remarks at the nationally broadcast memorial service on Wednesday night (the one attended by President Obama), Shelton pronounced heinous as “highness.” Unbelievable!

And in the PBS column [“Beastly Mispronunciations”](https://www.pbs.org/speak/speech/beastly/), they cite *The Big Book Of Beastly Mispronunciations: The Complete Opinionated Guide For The Careful Speaker* by Charles Harrington Elster, who offers this opinion:

> #### Heinous HAY-nis.
>
> This word is so frequently mispronounced by well-educated speakers (who ought to know better) that you’d think the dictionaries would have caved in by now and countenanced the blunder. To their credit, they have not.  HAY-nis is the only acceptable pronunciation of this word.  Do not say HEE-nis or HEE-nee-is (HEE- as in heat), both of which are HAY-nis and long-standing members of the Most Unwanted Beastly Mispronunciations Hit List. *Heinous* has two syllables, not three, and the first syllable is pronounced like the word *hay*, never like *he*. See **mischievous, grievous, intravenous**.

Comment: The [French word *haineux*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/haineux) does not have a diphthong; if it did, it would be spelled *haïneux*, like the verb *[haïr](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ha%C3%AFr)*, which does have a diphthong. (Although the French claim there are no diphthongs in French, just two vowels which happen to be next to each other.)

Comment: The pronunciation of the second syllable given by the "Big Book of Beastly Mispronunciations" assumes that the reader has the *weak vowel merger*, that is to say, that the pronunciation of an unstressed short i and a schwa are identical.

Comment: Another possibility for the ‘high’ pronunciation might be analogy/confusion with German, which would pronounce the first syllable approximately that way.  And BTW, as a southern-UK native, I'd usually pronounce the word to rhyme with, er, a part of the body…

Comment: @RobertFurber I wasn't really focusing on the precise character of the unstressed vowel in the word's second syllable, so whether you have the *Rosa’s–roses* merger there doesn't really matter as to which word is perceived, which cares only about the stressed vowel. *Highness, Linus, lettuce, pumice, furnace, Christmas* all end in either unstressed schwa or else in unstressed "schwi" depending on your merger, plus then that final /s/. I've updated my answer to focus on the stressed vowel, which is what matters: PRICE is considered nonstandard, FACE standard.

Comment: This touches on what my first instinct was when I heard it, that it is a *nonstandard* pronunciation. It's interesting to know exactly *why* it's nonstandard. Very interesting. Thanks.

Comment: "I have heard native speakers of English ... use the "highness" pronunciation, ... I have yet to uncover any documentation in support of this variation"
. . . . 
You have your "documentation". You heard native speakers use it. That's all you need. In English, dictionaries are descriptive. If they don't contain a pronunciation native speakers use, it is the dictionary which is wrong.

Comment: Well, I made it almost 60 years in the Appalachians, from Pittsburg to Macon, blissfully unaware of any pronunciation other than long I. I rather doubt I can change now. I landed here after trying to figure out which three "a" pronunciations were being referred to in a bunch of  -ei words.

Answer (score 7):

[Kentucky Fried Movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076257/)

> "Young lady, are you aware that to withhold evidence, pertinent to a
>   crime, so heinious..."
>
> "No."
>
> "Hineous?"
>
> "No."
>
> "Hinéous."
>
> "I think it's pronounced 'heenus'."
>
> "No, you wouldn't say 'your heenus'."
>
> "No! Ladies and gentlemen, I have it right here.
>   'Hyenas': Any of a family of cowardly, carnivorous beasts of Asia and Africa."

Comment: I've never heard of this movie before but I've just downloaded it! Here's a link to the courtroom scene you quoted: https://youtu.be/Pm1rif1fASk?t=369 *"No. You wouldn't say 'your heenus'."* 

Comment: Please try to elaborate on your answer.

Comment: Actually this answer, while amusing, doesn't answer the question. Which of the offered alternatives is the correct pronunciation?